# Jenkins - How to schedule job every period of days?

Tags: jenkins, schedule

I tried to schedule a job run every 28 days but still not have solution yet.
Please help!
Thank!

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation shows, using `*/X` executes in intervals of `X`.

So, applying this to the "day of month" field, under "Build periodically", you could use the following to build at some consistent point in time once every 28 days:

```
H H */28 * 2
```

As an example, the `2` at the end signifies that the build should run on a Tuesday.  Otherwise, it will probably build on whatever day of the week the current month started with.

Comment: But there is a problem: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12677/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it yet so I may be wrong, but how about putting days as hours.
For example, if you want to run Jenkins job every 10 days, you schedule it to run every 240 hours.

Comment: Hours (and multiples) must be <= 24, days <= 31, and minutes <= 59 as described in the built-in documentation.

Tuples like `H H */10  * *` meaning at a statically calculated *minute* (first H) of a calculated *hour* (second H) on every 10th *day* (third item) of every *month* (forth item) on every *day of the week* (last *) doesn't work the way the OP is asking because it would run on the 10th, 20th, 30th but not the 31, or 1, - 9th. that is, it leaves a 11 day gap between runs following months with 31 days, and an 18 or 19 day gap between February 20th and March 10th.